# Approximation to An Exponential Integral

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Is there any analytical approximation to an integral of this form?
$$
\int_{0}^t e^{-\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^k} dx
$$

This comes from integrating $(1-F(x))$, for $F(x)$ being the CDF of a [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=(x/a)^{k}$
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{t} \mathrm{e}^{-(x/a)^{}k} dx &= 
\frac{a}{k} \int\limits_{0}^{(t/a)^{k}} \mathrm{e}^{-z} z^{-1+1/k} dz \\
&= \frac{a}{k} \gamma (1/k, (t/k)^{k} )
\end{align}
$\gamma(s,z) = \int\limits_{0}^{z} t^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} dt$ is the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).